# Regex optional word in regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search some arrays with regular expressions. Some words should be "optional", which means it's good if they are in the string (for relevancy)

Here is my attempt:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:animal)? (lamina)/', $searchExpression, $matches);
```

It does not work though. What I am trying to achieve here is, the string must contain lamina, and may contain animal.
If the string contains both animal and lamina, it would have better relevancy then a match that just matches lamina.

How can I fix the regex? And how do I sort the matches, too see which one "matches" best.

i.e

```
$animalStuff = array('animal lamina', 'lamina', 'animal');
```

The first 2 items should match , the third should not. and animal lamina should probably be the most relevant. How do I perform the relevancy?

```
$animalStuff = array('animal lamina', 'lamina', 'animal');

$results = array();

foreach ($animalStuff as $searchExpression)
{
    preg_match_all('/(?:animal)? (lamina)/', $searchExpression, $matches);

    var_dump($matches);

    // Do something here to decide if it should be in the top of array, etc.
}
```

Counting the amount of matches, could probably get me the best relevancy I assume, but I just need to get the regex working first to try that out.

Comment: The space after the word needs to be optional too, otherwise just the second word alone will not match.

Comment: like if lamina is in the string ? /(lamina)/gi

Comment: Removing the space in regex, gives me results, but none of them contains "animal", as the first one should: rray(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "lamina" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "lamina" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "lamina" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "lamina" } }

Comment: Take off the non-capturing group if you want the word `animal` included. The `?:` makes it not capture, the trailing `?` makes the whole group optional.

Comment: What does that mean chris85? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Of when you would want to use a non-capturing group?

Comment: /(?animal)(lamina)/ does not give me the desired result, it was like that I assumed you meant?

Comment: You can see that example of using several capturing groups in the answer below. I can only  suggest chedcking and storing information on captured groups and then sort by the captured text count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
preg_match_all('/(animal.*?lamina)|(lamina)/', $searchExpression, $matches);
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nI5dH1/1)

Comment: Why the space? The space should not matter, it is the "word" i am specifically looking for

Comment: @JohnSvensson you mean to say, we can have strings like `"animal hello lamina"` also?

Comment: Yes, i am looking for words in strings, not a exact match string

Comment: @JohnSvensson then you can just use the pipe operator.. check the update :)

Comment: Well the problem is that lamina is still "required", "animal" can be there, do you understand? :)

Comment: The "animal" and "lamina", are not connected though. The are just separated words, where one of the words MUST BE THERE, and the other one can be there.

Answer (score 0):

(this should probably be a comment)

There are several problems here, most of which do away if you stop using regular expressions to find the matches. Hence why the requirement to use regexes?

e.g. consider:

```
function matchwords($allwords, $requiredwords, $subject)
{
   $subject=preg_replace("/\W/", ' ', $subject);
   $subject=explode(' ', $subject);
   if (count(array_intersect($requiredwords, $subject)) {
      return count(array_intersect($allwords, $subject));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Try benchmarking it - it may actually be faster than using regexes. With large word sets, inverting the arrays and using array_intersect_key() will likely be faster.